# Why can't the Web Browser find these modules, resolve, and compile the page?

Tags: reactjs, import, module

In a React project, I am trying to run the app on a live server in the web browser. However when I command **CD Ravenous** to go to the right file and **npm start**, the browser gives me the following error:

> ./src/index.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve './App' in '/Users/mauricemarkslag/ravenous/src'

I've checked if the imports have been filled in correctly, and that should be the case now I guess. However the error doesn't seem to be fixed with this code:

[Code file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEXWL.png)

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Romuv.png)

Does anybody know what I might do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, you should use `./app.css` instead of `./App.css`, and I am assuming that the file that you put in your question is `app.js`.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick reply. Yes the provided file is app.js. I changed the typo from ./App.css to ./app.css, but the error remains the same.

Comment: I found it myself! The problem was actually in index.js, so I was looking in the wrong folder. After changing '' import App from './App'; '' to '' import App from './components/App/app; '' the problem was solved.